# Empirical Risk and True Risk - Generalization Error Proof

Tags: machine-learning, computation-models, learning-theory

I showed that, over an uncountable domain,learner A and a distribution P, such that for every sample size m and all samples S from $P^m$
$$
: L_S(A(S)) − L_P (A(S))| = 1
$$
Now I wanna prove for countable domains. Lets assume X = N. I wanna prove that, for sample size m, and every $\epsilon> 0$, there exists a learner A and a distribution P over X, such that
for all samples S from $P^m$ we have
$$
|L_S(A(S)) − L_P (A(S))| ≥ 1 − \epsilon
$$

Not sure how to go about it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, welcome to CS.SE. Please use [Latex/Mathjax](https://cs.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) to make your formulas readable for other people.

Comment: @Watercrystal Thanks for the tips. I did the changes. I am new to this. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer (as, I presume, the question) uses the notation of the book [*Understanding Machine Learning: From Theory to Algorithms*](https://www.cs.huji.ac.il/%7Eshais/UnderstandingMachineLearning/) by Shai Shalev-Shwartz and Shai Ben-David.

Suppose our domain set is $\mathbb N$ and we are interested in binary classification. We want to show that there exists a distribution $P$ on $\mathbb N$ and a learning algorithm $A$ such that the difference between the *empirical error* $L_S(A(S))$ of the hypothesis $A(S)$ produced by $A$ given the finite sample set $S$ and the *true error* $L_P(A(S))$ is large, i.e. the hypothesis $A(S)$ performs well on the training data but does not generalize.

So to prove the statement, let $m \geq 0$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ and consider a binary classification scenario over the domain set $\mathbb N$.

We define a learner $A$ as follows: Given a set $S \subset \mathbb N \times \{0, 1\}$ of $m$ samples, $A$ outputs the hypothesis
$$ h_S(x) = 
\begin{cases}
y, & \text{if } (x, y) \in S \\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases} $$
Clearly, the empirical error of the hypothesis produced by $A$ will be $0$ for any training set $S$ as we defined the output of $A$ specifically to be correct for all samples in $S$.

It remains to construct a probability distribution over $\mathbb N$ such that the true error of the hypothesis $A(S)$ is at least $1 - \varepsilon$ for any choice of $S$.
Recall that the true error of a hypothesis $h$ w.r.t. a distribution $P$ is defined as
$$L_P(h) = \Pr_{(x, y) \sim P}[h(x) \neq y].$$

We now fix the labels in our distribution to always be 1 to ensure that $A(S)$ errs on all inputs not contained in the sample set $S$.
Hence the task now reduces to assigning probabilities to each $n \in \mathbb N$ such that the combined probability of any $m$ points forming such a sample set is bounded by $\varepsilon$.
To achieve this, consider the distribution $P \colon \mathbb N \to [0, 1]$ with
$$
P(n) = 
\begin{cases}
\varepsilon / m, & \text{if } n \leq m - 1 \\
\varepsilon / (m \cdot 2^{n - m + 1}), & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
If we consider any sample set $S \subset \mathbb N$ of size $m$, we find that
$$ \Pr_{x \sim P}[x \in S] =  \sum_{n \in S} P(n) \leq \sum_{n \in S} \frac{\varepsilon}{m} = \varepsilon.$$
Hence, using the learner $A$ on a sample set $S$ of size $m$ drawn using the distribution $P$ yields a hypothesis $h_S$ with
$$
\begin{align}
L_P(A(S)) 
&= \Pr_{x \sim P}[h_S(x) \neq 1] \\
&= \Pr_{x \sim P}[x \notin S] \\
&= 1 - \Pr_{x \sim P}[x \in S] \\
&\geq 1 - \varepsilon.
\end{align}
$$
To finish everything off, recall that we defined $A$ such that $L_S(A(S) = 0$, yielding
$$|L_S(A(S) - L_P(A(S))| \geq 1 - \varepsilon.$$

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I could make partial sense out of it. I have a couple of questions. So, what I understand is you wanna construct a probability distribution that doesn't generalize. 
Why did we consider combined probability of m points to be bounded by $\epsilon$.
Also, how did you come up with that distribution with that otherwise statement.

Comment: Note that the produced hypothesis $A(S)$ correctly classifies all points in the sample set $S$ it was trained on. As we judge how well $A(S)$ generalizes by the measure of the set that it does not err on it follows that in order to have it be incorrect on a set of measure $\geq 1 - \varepsilon$ we must bound the measure of $S$ by $\varepsilon$ -- and the easiest way to do that is to ensure that none of the $m$ samples in $S$ has probability greater than $\varepsilon / m$.

Comment: As for coming up with the distribution: Note that to comply with the the condition outlined in the previous comment we have some restrictions on it. I just took the well-known series $\sum_{n \in \mathbb N} 1 / 2^n = 1$ and modified it a bit to get a distribution where no point is given a probability greater than $\varepsilon / m$ by shifting and scaling it a bit.